# JBoss 5.1 cluster fails with EAR

Tags: jboss5.x

We have 2 servers that cluster just fine when we do not deploy any EAR files.

Server 1:

```
2015-03-26 08:23:00,339 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember] (Incoming-13,10.200.51.14:62610) org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember$ControlMembershipListener@1f15227c got new view [10.200.51.14:62610|1] [10.200.51.14:62610, 10.200.51.16:58992], old view is [10.200.51.14:62610|0] [10.200.51.14:62610]
2015-03-26 08:23:00,339 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember] (Incoming-13,10.200.51.14:62610) I am (10.200.51.14:62610)
2015-03-26 08:23:00,339 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember] (Incoming-13,10.200.51.14:62610) New Members : 1 ([10.200.51.16:58992])
2015-03-26 08:23:00,355 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember] (Incoming-13,10.200.51.14:62610) All Members : 2 ([10.200.51.14:62610, 10.200.51.16:58992])
2015-03-26 08:24:32,140 INFO  [org.jboss.cache.RPCManagerImpl] (Incoming-16,10.200.51.14:62610) Received new cluster view: [10.200.51.14:62610|2] [10.200.51.14:62610]
```

Server2:

```
2015-03-26 08:23:00,011 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember] (main) All Members : 2 ([10.200.51.14:62610, 10.200.51.16:58992])
```

Multicast is successfully configured and working.

The clustering does NOT occur when EAR files are included at `JBoss startup`.

We see NAKACK messages (on Server1) when Server2 starts... but clustering does not complete.

```
2015-03-26 14:28:41,105 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (Incoming-2,10.200.51.14:7900) sender 10.200.51.16:7900 not found in xmit_table
2015-03-26 14:28:41,105 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (Incoming-2,10.200.51.14:7900) range is null
```

We see multiple `NAKACK` messages (on Server2) when it starts:

```
2015-03-26 14:27:47,488 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (OOB-4,10.200.51.16:50648) 10.200.51.16:50648] discarded message from non-member 10.200.51.14:59139, my view is [10.200.51.16:50648|0] [10.200.51.16:50648]
2015-03-26 14:27:47,675 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (OOB-4,10.200.51.16:50648) 10.200.51.16:50648] discarded message from non-member 10.200.51.14:59139, my view is [10.200.51.16:50648|0] [10.200.51.16:50648]
```

and

```
2015-03-26 14:28:34,038 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (Incoming-4,10.200.51.16:50648) 10.200.51.16:50648] discarded message from non-member 10.200.51.14:59139, my view is [10.200.51.16:50648|0] [10.200.51.16:50648]
2015-03-26 14:28:34,038 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (Incoming-9,10.200.51.16:50648) sender 10.200.51.14:59139 not found in xmit_table
2015-03-26 14:28:34,038 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (Incoming-9,10.200.51.16:50648) range is null
2015-03-26 14:28:40,356 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (Incoming-2,10.200.51.16:7900) sender 10.200.51.14:7900 not found in xmit_table
2015-03-26 14:28:40,356 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (Incoming-2,10.200.51.16:7900) range is null
```

We also see a `JBoss` messaging error on Server2 after the `EAR file` completes its deployment:

```
2015-03-26 14:32:38,557 ERROR [org.jboss.messaging.util.ExceptionUtil] (WorkManager(2)-7) SessionEndpoint[ej-53z3kq7i-1-gg3wjq7i-1d1bnk-gf1k5a] createConsumerDelegate [4k-dcm4kq7i-1-gg3wjq7i-1d1bnk-gf1k5a]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember@692dba20 response not received from 10.200.51.14:59139 - there may be others
    at org.jboss.messaging.core.impl.postoffice.GroupMember.multicastControl(GroupMember.java:262)
```

This application is CA Identity Manager `R12.6 SP4`, with 2 `EAR` files involved.
We have discussed this clustering issue with `CA`, and they indicate something is mis-configured within the `JBoss AS`.

Does anyone have any idea how we might troubleshoot and resolve this problem???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762887/jboss-ehcache-replication-exception-sender-not-found-in-xmit-table